# How do I disable Audiofocus in webview?

Tags: webview, android-webview

I'm making an application that plays videos in webview.
I want to play other music apps while keeping the video playing in the webview.
Is there any way to ignore or disable Audiofocus?

sorry, I'm using a translation tool by DeepL.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.